# Regex to Find Four Open Brackets without a Closing Bracket

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all the places in my .less files that are nested 4+ levels deep without being closed.

Here is where I'm currently at on Rubular:
http://rubular.com/r/a6uWyH0mUv

And in case you'd prefer to see the example here on SO:

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    li {
        width: 25%;
        a {
            color: @blue;
            span {
                font-weight: normal;
            }
        }
    }
}

ul {
    width:100%;
    li {
        width: 25%;
        a {
            color: @blue;
        }
    }
}

ul {
    width:100%;
    li {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

ul {
    width:100%;
}
```

The only one I want to match is the very first test string which has 4 nested css properties.

Through various experiments, I've been able to get very close but I still end up matching parts of the strings that shouldn't get caught by the regex.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language or platform are you using ??? Plus in your sample input I see everything is closed properly ?!

Comment: I'll run the search in Sublime Text 2 ... tried to find documentation on which language ST2 uses but couldn't. Sorry, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Sublime test 2 uses geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*?(?:\{[^}]*?){4}(.*?\})

.*? makes sure to find the first one, not really necessary
(?:\{[^}]*?) finds 4 opening brackets without closing ones
(.*?\}) capturing group until the first closing bracket.
```

If that's not exactly what you want, it can be easily modified.

Solving your request in the comments:

```
.*?(?:\{[^}]*?){4}(.*?)\}
```

will just give you the text contained within the brackets (`font-weight: normal;`). All I did was remove the closing bracket from the capturing group.

and

```
.*?(?:\{[^}]*?){3}(\n[^\n]*?\{.*?\})
```

will solve your second request. Note that this way is very hackish and I don't think it will work under all circumstances. I recommend the first one, or tinkering with this one a bit.

As for it crashing in Sublime Test 2, I'm not sure if I can help -- it's working for me!

Comment: @brianrhea thanks. I want to note that the first clause in the regex: `.*?` is totally useless and will only slow the regex down unless you only want to match the first instance of {{{{.

Comment: Actually, that first clause does seem to come in handy if there is a nested rule that closes, but then other { follow it. See the updated examples: http://rubular.com/r/dD9zcBXiYA

If I remove that first clause, the first example is no longer matched. 

Unfortunately, when I run this in Sublime, it crashes:
(?s)(?:\{[^}]*?){4}(.*?\})

From what I've found, (?s) equates to the /m option to make . match new lines.

Comment: This is definitely getting me very close to what I need, so thank you very much. I have no problem marking your answer successful because it's getting me there. But the ideal would even be that the only thing that's matched is:

span {
  font-weight: normal;
}

or just:

font-weight: normal;

Comment: @brianrhea I'll edit this in a minute so you can get what you need :)

Comment: I went to the rubular example provided at rubular.com/r/dD9zcBXiYA and updated the RegEx to what you provided:

(?:\{[^}]*?){4}(.*?)\}

It didn't match the text within the fourth block of braces. Apologies if I misstated or if I'm missing something in the example. Can you visit the rubular example and confirm that your Regex is matching "font-weight: normal;"

Comment: Huh. I can confirm that they both work. make sure multiline is on (add  m to the box on the right if it's not already there.) Otherwise, the .*s won't match newline characters, which we could fix, it would just be super annoying.

Comment: see rubular.com/r/Yl22kQ3nR1 and rubular.com/r/XC1lTMpWkW

Answer (score 1):

`[{][^}]*[{][^}]*[{][^}]*[{](.*)` should do the trick.